# How to upgrade WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm

I have an old version of WebStorm, and I do have a license for it. How do I upgrade my WebStorm version to the newest one and transfer my license to the newer installation?

Comment: Your old license is probably not transferable to the new version.

Comment: @Barmar I think it is, because it got renewed automatically, after the new versions were released, and it's the same price.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact JetBrains support. They've always been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download a new version from https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download and register it with your license (using your JetBrains account or with offline code). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/registering-webstorm.html

Should you have problems registering it, please contact support